# Handling key value pair in response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following response.

```
response: {
      "json": {
         "response":{ 
           "servicetype":"", 
           "functiontype":"", 
           "statuscode":"0", 
           "statusmessage":"Success", 
           "data":             
               [
                 {
                   "graphtype":"headcountgraph", 
                   "xlabel":"state", 
                   "ylabel":"count",
                   "s1":"contact", 
                   "s2":"User",
                   "data": 
                        [
                             "Total Contacts: 1 Users: 36",
                             [
                               { 
                                 "x":"India", 
                                 "s1":"3", 
                                 "s2":"3", 
                                 "lat":"22",       
                                 "long":"77" 
                                }
                             ]
                      ]
                 }

               ]
          }
      }
  };
```

I need to Assign `$scope.state = India`,

How to fetch that ? I have tried giving `$scope.state = json.response.data[0].data[1][0].x`, which returns undefined data.

The thing is it has key and entry. I really lacking to fetch entry values from the code.

I gave code this way

```
   $.each(data, function(key, entry) { x.push(parseInt(entry.x)});
```

but it gives me values [india] in my console.

Comment: Do You need only "India" from whole response?

Comment: Yes . I need to assign it for $scope.state = India

Comment: You can get this value via JSON object: `JSON.parse( <string> ).json.response.data[0].data[1][0].x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving  `$scope.state = response.json.response.data[0].data[1][0].x ;`

Your statement doesn't start from the root `response` object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.

```
json.response.data[0].data[1]
```

returns the following object:

```
{"x":"India","s1":"3","s2":"3","lat":"22","long":"77"}
```

You can filter by the `x` key with:

```
json.response.data[0].data.filter(o => o[0].x == "India")[0];
```